# StackScrollView issue with delegate ID MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a stack scroll view app (like the Twitter and Facebook apps) using PSStackedView

It's creates the view with this stack:

AppDelegate

```
// set root controller as stack controller
MenuRootController *menuController = [[MenuRootController alloc] init];
self.stackController = [[PSStackedViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.stackController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Root nav controller has a UItable, a cell touch loads the next view

```
// Load Home Stories table

PSStackedViewController *stackController = XAppDelegate.stackController;
UIViewController*viewController = nil;

while ([stackController.viewControllers count]) {
    //NSLog(@"launchStories");
    [stackController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

viewController = [[TestView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:nil];     

((TestView *)viewController).indexNumber = [stackController.viewControllers count];
viewController.view.width = roundf((self.view.width - stackController.leftInset)/2);

if (viewController) {
    [XAppDelegate.stackController pushViewController:viewController fromViewController:nil animated:YES];
}
```

In this view I want to use the MBProgressHUD (https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD/) to display a nice loading XML message

```
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view.window];
    [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];

    HUD.delegate =  self ;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

But

```
HUD.delegate =  self ;
```

Throws an warning and the app crashes

```
Assigning to 'id<MBProgressHUDDelegate>' from incompatible type 'TestView *'
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations to try and find the current controller but to no avail, I can find the width of the current controller for instance with

```
PSStackedViewController *stackController = XAppDelegate.stackController;
NSLog(@"%f",stackController.view.width);
```

which prints 748.000000. But I can't find work out what 'self' should be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestView needs to implement the MBProgressHUDDelegate protocol. In TestView.h make it look something like this:

```
@interface TestView : ClassYouInheritFrom <MBProgressHUDDelegate>
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you. I hate it when it's something so *obvious*